# onbeforeunload custom message not working on chrome

Tags: html

I need help with something for my site I'm working on.
I have searched stack overflow and found no answers for this. 
here is the code I'm trying to use.

`<script>
 function dontgo(){
 return "are you sure you want to leave the site"
 }
 </script>`

Comment: sum1 help please

Comment: sum1 help me please

Comment: i still haven't figured this out